# vsce (VSCode Extension CLI) "command not found" error

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install, vscode-extensions

In order to package and publish my VSCode Extension, I ran the installation command for vsce.

`npm install -g vsce`

While attempting to run further commands with vsce, it results in the following error:

`command not found: vsce`

[the terminal messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIsjL.png)

node is on `v16.16.0`, npm `8.11.0`

The following is included in my *package.json* file:

`"dependencies":{ "vsce": "^2.9.3"}`

How can I solve this? Also, is there another way to publish the extension in Marketplace without using the Command Line?

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem, but installing with homebrew fixed it. The command is brew install vsce.

Answer (score 0):

You can add path to you bash file or create a link in /usr/bin folder

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/@vscode/vsce/vsce ./vsce
```

Now you can run vsce commands in terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows Powershell
C://users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/npm/vsce publish
will do the job